# How can I change the structure of the links that Codeigniter create_links() generates?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a small blogging application.  There is a clear separation between its back-end and its front-end:

1. The back-end is an **API**, made with Codeigniter 3, that spits out
   pages, posts, pagination etc.
2. This API is consumed by an **AngularJS** (v. 1.7.x) front-end;

The **front-end posts controller** looks like this:

```
// All posts
.controller('PostsController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    //Get current page (?page=2, ?page=3 etc)
    const currPage = window.location.search;

    // Get all the posts on the current page 
    $http.get('api/' + currPage).then(function(response) {

        // Posts
        $scope.posts = response.data.posts;

        // posts pagination
        $scope.pagination = response.data.pagination;
    });
}])
```

I have a problem with the pagination that Codeigniter (API) generates caused by the fact that its root is  `http://apiblog.com/api/`. The pagination's HTML is this:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="http://apiblog.com/api/" data-ci-pagination-page="1" rel="prev">&lsaquo;</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://apiblog.com/api/" data-ci-pagination-page="1" rel="start">1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><span>2</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://apiblog.com/api/?page=3" data-ci-pagination-page="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://apiblog.com/api/?page=4" data-ci-pagination-page="4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://apiblog.com/api/?page=3" data-ci-pagination-page="3" rel="next">&rsaquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

By looking at the front-end posts controller, you can see that the pagination links should **miss** the `api/` part. It **should** be:

```
<ul class="pagination">
    <li><a href="http://apiblog.com/" data-ci-pagination-page="1" rel="prev">&lsaquo;</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://apiblog.com/" data-ci-pagination-page="1" rel="start">1</a></li>
    <li class="active"><span>2</span></li>
    <li><a href="http://apiblog.com/?page=3" data-ci-pagination-page="3">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://apiblog.com/?page=4" data-ci-pagination-page="4">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="http://apiblog.com/?page=3" data-ci-pagination-page="3" rel="next">&rsaquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

In the **Posts** controller responsible with displaying and paginating the posts in the **front-end**:

```
private function _initPagination($path, $totalRows, $query_string_segment = 'page') {
    //load and configure pagination 
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url($path);
    $config['query_string_segment'] = $query_string_segment; 
    $config['enable_query_strings'] =TRUE;
    $config['reuse_query_string'] =TRUE;
    $config['total_rows'] = $totalRows;
    $config['per_page'] = 12;
    if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
        $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
    }
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $limit = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;

    return ['limit' => $limit, 'offset' => $offset];
}

public function index() {

    //call initialization method
    $config = $this->_initPagination("/", $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows());

    $data = $this->Static_model->get_static_data();
    //$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->get_as_array();
    $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
    $data['pages'] = $this->Pages_model->get_pages();
    $data['categories'] = $this->Categories_model->get_categories();  

//use limit and offset returned by _initPaginator method
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($config['limit'], $config['offset']);

    // All posts
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json')->set_output(json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

In the back-end (dashboard), the code for the posts is:

```
public function index() {

    //load and configure pagination 
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $config['base_url'] = base_url("/dashboard/posts");
    $config['query_string_segment'] = 'page';
    $config['total_rows'] = $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows();
    $config['per_page'] = 10;

    if (!isset($_GET[$config['query_string_segment']]) || $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] < 1) {
        $_GET[$config['query_string_segment']] = 1;
    }
    $limit = $config['per_page'];
    $offset = ($this->input->get($config['query_string_segment']) - 1) * $limit;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);

    $data = $this->get_data();
    $data['posts'] = $this->Posts_model->get_posts($limit, $offset);
    $data['offset'] = $offset;

    $this->load->view('partials/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('dashboard/posts');
    $this->load->view('partials/footer');
}
```

Given that the pagination items are generated "behind the scenes" by `$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();`, I was unable to achieve the necessary configuration of the pagination links.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: can't you set base_url to http://apiblog.com/ ?, because base_url is used in the function create_links() of the core library pagination.php. Or maybe extending the pagination library would be an option?

Comment: @Vickel The application is meant to function regardless of the domain name so the base url is dynamic: `$root  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$config['base_url'] = $root;`.

Comment: Just use `$config['base_url']  = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];`

Comment: @ascsoftw My back-end (Dashboard) also shows paginated posts. I need `$root = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; $root .= str_replace(basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']),"",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']); $config['base_url'] = $root;`, i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `_initPagination` where you have following line of code

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url($path);
```

You can change the above to

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $path;
```

Comment: You haven't provided any code related to CI. Need to see the function that is fetching the data.

Comment: May I know if there is any difference in URLs being called from API and your Dashboard?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200441/discussion-between-razvan-zamfir-and-ascsoftw).